# Rails Api with devise_token_auth gives "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, omniauth-facebook, devise-token-auth

I want to build RailsAPI with facebook login, so I chose `devise_token_auth`. I followed the instruction and run `rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth`, my routes look like

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

So it is the stuff that comes from generator. 
I registered my app at facebook for developers, store the facebook-key and facebook-secret in env file. When I hit the first time `localhost:3000/auth/facebook` it redirectem me to facebook auth popup, I clicked the button and then the error comes.

[image]

Should I override the controller from devise with my own? How to do that?
Or there are any other solutions?

I would like to mention that is my first time building API with rails.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the problem when rewrite `assign_provider_attrs`

route.rb

`mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth' , controllers: {
      omniauth_callbacks: 'authentication_rails/omniauth_callbacks'
    }`

controllers/concerns/authentication_rails/omniauth_callbacks_controller

`module AuthenticationRails
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController
    protected
    # break out provider attribute assignment for easy method extension
    def assign_provider_attrs(user, auth_hash)
      if auth_hash['provider'] == 'facebook'
        user.assign_attributes({
          nickname: auth_hash['info']['nickname'],
          name:     auth_hash['info']['name'],
          image:    auth_hash['info']['image'],
          email:    auth_hash['info']['email']
        })
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end`